# F# Fake run in WSL2 resolves the program path in the hosting Windows, not in Linux

Tags: f#, f#-fake, wsl-2

**Environment**

- WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 from Windows 10 Home
- Linux .Net Core 3.1
- Node 12.18.3 + NPM 6.14.6 + Yarn 1.22.5

**Problem**

I'm following the [SAFE Stack quick start](https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/) but the FAKE build script fails:

```
$ dotnet fake build --target run
```

But FAKE cannot find the `npm` binary:

```
Target          Duration
------          --------
Clean           00:00:00.0053439
InstallClient   00:00:00.1517122   (npm was not found in path. Please install it and make sure it's available from your path. See https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/#install-pre-requisites for more info)
```

**Question**

By inserting debug messages, it seems that the FAKE `build.fsx` script resolves the PATH from the hosting Windows, not from the WSL2 Linux environment:

```
DEBUG: Some "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ls.EXE"
```

Sample from the script:

```
// My Debug
printfn "DEBUG: %A" (ProcessUtils.tryFindFileOnPath "ls")
// The actual script
let npmPath =
    match ProcessUtils.tryFindFileOnPath "npm" with
    | Some path -> path
    | None ->
        "npm was not found in path. Please install it and make sure it's available from your path. "
        + "See https://safe-stack.github.io/docs/quickstart/#install-pre-requisites for more info"
        |> failwith
```

*=> Is it a bug or I'm missing something here?* (I'm quite new to .Net and F#)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, that was something quite stupid from my side: In a previous mixed Windows + WSL setup I added to `bash_aliases` a line with `alias dotnet=dotnet.exe`. I should have removed it when I installed the Linux .Net Core packages

Case closed